# SQL same column name allowed

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run this query in SQL Server

```
SELECT custid AAA, companyname AAA
FROM Sales.Customers
WHERE country = 'USA'
```

It's running fine. But now the result set have duplicate column name(AAA). Why SQL server allow this to happen? How an application works if it needs to reference the column name? I know if you put this query as a derived table SQL will stop you. like

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     (SELECT custid AAA, companyname AAA
      FROM Sales.Customers
      WHERE country = 'USA') BBB
```

SQL Server reports an error:

> The column 'AAA' was specified multiple times for 'BBB'

What's the logic behind this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reason for this problem is:

**1st Query**

```
SELECT custid AAA, companyname AAA
   FROM Sales.Customers
   WHERE country = 'USA'
```

Here, you are assigning column alias at the time of output, so `AAA` is as column name(alias actually) attached at the time of returning result, but i guess you will see only 1st column with `AAA` other will be removed because of possible confliction during further reference. so here you are not getting error.

---

**2nd Query**

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT custid AAA, companyname AAA
    FROM Sales.Customers
    WHERE country = 'USA') BBB
```

Here you got error because, you are selecting records from [Inline View](http://michaelmclaughlin.info/db1/lesson-5-querying-data/inline-views/) with name `BBB`, here that Inner Query(inline view) is considered as a Table(for your `SELECT * FROM` statement), and as we know - basically Table can not have multiple same column name, because of that you are getting error that BBB has multiple `AAA` column.

Answer (score 2):

This can be explained by understanding order of execution of different logical phases of query execution. [**Query Execution Order MSDN**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/70efeffe-76b9-4b7e-b4a1-ba53f5d21916/order-of-execution-of-sql-queries&ei=4HgNU4vVDs-ziQfgp4AY&usg=AFQjCNGu5dJDdfyt8dil0sc1xx795jFnEQ&sig2=YdOVvJudnj7a_vNyYkGftw&bvm=bv.61965928,d.aGc)

In SQL Server the order is `FROM > WHERE > SELECT` i.e. **first FROM clause is executed then WHERE clause and last is the SELECT list.**

Now in your first query , all matching rows from table Sales.Customers are fetched and then then afterwards columns specified in `SELECT` list are pulled out   and then Alias names are applied.

In your second query , the inner query is executed successfully as the first query but when the outer query's `FROM` clause tries to fetch columns from resultset returned by inner query , it finds duplicate columns and throws error.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving two same aliases name to different column that will render as duplicate column in one table.

That's why it is giving error.

If you will make it different alias name then error will not occur.just try it and let me know whether it will work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your guys kind replies.
I would agree with Nikhil Butani. Here are my thoughts.

We all know the basic rules about table columns
1. Must have a name
2. Name must be unique.

The First query I provided

SELECT custid AAA, companyname AAA
   FROM Sales.Customers
   WHERE country = 'USA'

is actually a RESULT. It's not a table, so doesn't need to comply with the rules. But when I use it as the derived table in the second query, it must be a valid table. The columns rules apply.

Here are more interesting things. Change the Query 1 as following

```
SELECT custid AAA, companyname + '' 
   FROM Sales.Customers
   WHERE country = 'USA'
```

It makes the second column no name since it's an expression. Running OK since it's just a result.
Put it into a derived table

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT custid AAA, companyname + '' 
       FROM Sales.Customers
       WHERE country = 'USA'
) AS AAA
```

SQL Server returns: No column name was specified for column 2 of 'AAA'.

That also explains why in derived table syntax, you must assign an alias to the table (AS AAA) because table must have a name.

Thanks all.